# C++ How to check the size of an element inside a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a string array `std::string words[4000]` full of random words. I want to check the size of any random word within this array. I tried:

```
int x = words[rnd].length();
```

and

`int x = words[rnd].size();`

and

`int x = sizeof(words[rnd]);`

where rnd is a number returned from rand(). But both times x gets the value of 0, and sizeof() always returns 28. What am i doing wrong here?

For anyone who wants to check the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
std::string words[4000];        `
void fread(std::string fname, std::string  words[], const int & nwords)

    {

        std::ifstream ifile(fname.c_str(), std::ios::in);

        if (!ifile)
        {
            std::cout << " Couldn’t read the file " << fname;
            exit(-1);
            //return;
        }

        int count = 0;
        while (ifile && count < nwords)
            ifile >> words[count++];
        ifile.close();
    }

    `int main()`
    `{`

        srand(time(NULL));
        int nwords = 4000;
        int rnd = rand() % nwords;
        int x = words[rnd].length()/3;
        fread("<location>", words, nwords);
        int* hintloc = new int[x];
        std::cout << words[rnd]; //this checks whether i have the right word
        const int hangsize = 19;
        bool chk;
        std::cout << "\n\n\t\t\tGET READY FOR HANGMAN!\n\n\t\tGuess this word: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            hintloc[i] = rand() % words[rnd].size();
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (hintloc[i] == hintloc[j])
                    i--;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words[rnd].size(); i++)
        {
            chk = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            {
                if (i == hintloc[j])
                {
                    std::cout << words[rnd].at(i)<<" ";
                    chk = false;
                }
            }
            if (chk == true)
                std::cout << "_ ";
        }

        delete[] hintloc;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you made sure that `rnd` is within 0..3999?

Comment: Also, `sizeof(std::string)` will not give you the length of string. It will return the size, in bytes, of the `string` class/struct.

Comment: How are you initializing `words`?

Comment: @gurka yes i have `rnd=rand()%4000`

Comment: @GregKikola i used a txt which contains 4000 words

Comment: Are you sure that the text file is being opened and read correctly? Maybe you should edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @GregKikola yes i have verified that the text file is being opened correctly

Comment: @LilShah You should post a [mcve]. Without it we can't really diagnose your problem.

Comment: Your first two code snippets will do exactly what you say you want. (The third is nonsense). So the problem is in the code that you haven't shown.

Comment: @LilShah You don't need to use a text file of 4000 words to figure out how to get the length of a string in an array. All you need is an array of strings: `string words[2] = {"hello", "world"};` then `auto x = words[0].length();`.

Comment: Is your problem about getting a random index or the size of a string?

Comment: Have you intialized the `words` array ?

Comment: You should fix your formatting. Select your code and use the Code Sample button.

Comment: I ran your code and I'm not sure what it's supposed to be doing that it's not doing, but it seems to work (except `system("pause")` doesn't work with my operating system - that isn't portable). And if I print the size of `words[rnd]` I get the expected length. Maybe you should use your debugger to figure out what's going on or else clarify what it is that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to initialise the `words` array so elements have non-zero length, before using those elements.  If you don't do that, the elements will be default-initialised.   A default-initialised `std::string` will have `length()` and `size()` members both give a result of zero (since they do the same thing).

If you are reading strings from a file, and checking later reveals they have length zero, then either the file contains all zero-length strings or an error has occurred reading the file.

`sizeof(words[rnd])` gives `sizeof std::string`, which is a size of the `std::string` type.   That has no relationship to the size of the string data held by any actual instance of `std::string` (e.g. `words[rnd]`).

Comment: i have verified multiple times that the strings are being read from the file and saved into the array 'words'. However the size being returned is still 0. And no the file is not empty. Initialising to a different value before reading from the files returns the length of what i initialised to, even if i call the size() function after reading the txt file

Comment: Maybe so.  But the problem is in your code and the data it works on, whether you show it here or not.   But, unless you provide an MCVE that exhibits your total problem (i.e. that someone else can use to recreate the exact same problem) - which you haven't - people have no option but to point out such possibilities.   But if the file has been verified as correctly read, and the `.size()` for strings returns zero, then presumably your method of verification is flawed.

Comment: So i tried replacing all instances of `x` with its value, `words[rnd].size()`. For some reason, that correctly returned the length value of the respective string. The problem, apparently, was in assigning that to `x`.

Comment: Well .. your code did have `int x = words[rnd].length()/3;`.  You are aware that `/3` divides by three?   And that integer division rounds toward zero?